# Dart Restful Server doesnt show response data

Tags: dart

I was not 100% sure on how to create a Restful Dart API I can make calls to, but i wanted to try.  I wrote the following code:

```
import "package:rpc/rpc.dart";
import "dart:io";
final ApiServer _apiServer = new ApiServer(prettyPrint:true);
main() async{
  _apiServer.addApi(new TestServer());

  HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 8088);
  server.listen(_apiServer.httpRequestHandler);
  print('Server listening on http://${server.address.host}:'
      '${server.port}');
}

@ApiClass(name:'test_server', version: 'v1', description: 'This is a test server api to ping for some quick sample data.')
class TestServer {

  @ApiMethod(method:'GET', path: 'users')
  List<User> getUsers(){
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    return users;
  }

  @ApiMethod(method: 'GET', path: 'users/{id}')
  User getUser(int id){
    User u;

    ///TODO: Guts of User.
    u = new User(id, "f_test_$id", "f_test_$id");

    return u;
  }

  @ApiMethod(method:'POST', path: 'users/user/{id}/add')
  User postUser(int id, UserData usr){
    User u;

    ///TODO:  Post the user.
    u = User.fromUsrData(usr);

    return u;
  }
}
```

It is a pretty simple, small one which isnt actually doing anything.

When I run the dart file it will say something like:

```
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:64969
Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8088
```

So it makes me believe that i should be able to ping the server in localhost.  I make a call in my browser to `http://localhost:8088/test_server/v1/users`

and it says: `{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid request, missing API name and/or version: http://localhost:8088/."}}` which confuses me.

Did i do something wrong somewhere in my definition or how to access the localhost API?

**EDIT**  It seems that when I go to that URL, it sits in a perpetual state of pending.  It doesnt do do anything other than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper understanding of the issue, changing the name around etc, It seems that my server was having some issues so i needed to end the Dart execution, and restart the server.

When trying to go to the link again: http://localhost:8088/test/v1/users
it worked exactly as it should.